# AccessibilityService: Query all current notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, accessibilityservice

With the new `NotificationListenerService` introduced in 4.3, it's possible to query all currenty active notifications using `NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications()`. Is something similar possible with the `AccessibilityService`? I wouldn't mind keeping track of them myself (store them temporarily once a new notification comes in), but it seems that there's no "`onRemoved`"-event for the `AccessibilityService`, so it's impossible to keep track of which notifications are still active and which have already been dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this isn't possible on pre-4.3. I've resorted to storing the notifications locally as they come in, but this isn't a very good approach since there's no way to tell when a notification was removed.